# Fetching data from multiple tables in yii

Tags: yii

I have 2 tables

### AutoScriptArgumentClass

id
ScriptArgumentClass

### AutoTestScriptMeta

id
AutoTestScript_id
ScriptArgumentClass_id

here is my query.

```
select sac.id,sac.ScriptArgumentClassType
from AutoScriptArgumentClass sac,AutoTestScriptMeta tsm
where tsm.ScriptArgumentClass_id = sac.id
and tsm.AutoTestScript_id=129
```

how do I write this in yii

I would like to have in this manner:

```
**$data=AutoTestScript::model()->findAll('Category_id=:parent_id',
        array(':parent_id'=>(int) $_POST['TestCaseCategory']));**

        $data=CHtml::listData($data,'id','ScriptName');
        foreach($data as $value=>$name)
        {
            echo CHtml::tag('option',
            array('value'=>$value),CHtml::encode($name),true);
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this will not be possible, as you are trying to get the data from multiple table into an instance of a CActiveRecordModel of a particular table.

This model does not have the instances of the columns of the other table, hence it cannot not avail them to you.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible in two condition. first you write a function in in your controller which contain the proper query and call the function from cgrid view or you can check the page more efficient way
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/281/searching-and-sorting-by-related-model-in-cgridview/

make sure the tables maintain the reletaionship. if your tables are in MYISAM format change it into INODB and try.. hope its works for you